# Android - How to get a contact from call log?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am trying to get contacts from call log. I can get the contact numbers from main contacts using this code :

```
    public void getContacts(View view) {

    Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intentContact, 0);

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{

    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        try {
        to.setText(getContactInfo(intent));
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
                 // Do nothing ;)
        }

    }

}
protected String getContactInfo(Intent intent)
{
    String phoneNumber = to.getText().toString();
    Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
       String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
      if(phoneNumber.endsWith(">"))
          phoneNumber += ", "+name;
        else
         phoneNumber += name;
        String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

        if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            hasPhone = "true";
        else
            hasPhone = "false" ;

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone))


        {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {   phoneNumber = phoneNumber + " <" + phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))+">";


               }
            phones.close();
        }


    }
    cursor.close();
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

What this does is when we click a "Contact" button it open a list with all the contacts, the user can select any contact and that selected contact will be added in the "To" field. I want to do the exactly same thing, but instead of displaying all the contacts i want to display only those who were recently used (call log) for selection.

Also it would be nice if you can tell how to do this with groups also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this going using my own version.  i used a dialog and handed it the cursor to the call log. Here is the function:

```
public void getCallLog() {

    String[] callLogFields = { android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME /* im not using the name but you can*/};
    String viaOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    String WHERE = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " >0"; /*filter out private/unknown numbers */

    final Cursor callLog_cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, callLogFields,
            WHERE, null, viaOrder);

    AlertDialog.Builder myversionOfCallLog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getActivity());

    android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
            callLog_cursor.moveToPosition(item);

            Log.v("number", callLog_cursor.getString(callLog_cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)));

            callLog_cursor.close();

        }
    };
    myversionOfCallLog.setCursor(callLog_cursor, listener,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    myversionOfCallLog.setTitle("Choose from Call Log");
    myversionOfCallLog.create().show();
}
```

Comment: great solution! Could you please help me know how can I display names in the dialog rather than the phone numbers?

Comment: just pull one of these: https://eu1.proxysite.com/process.php?d=QkR26Qu3Tx1YTzfcIrFEoeoRHuCtkB7y8TrqA0zcbaqR9kpzfSZC8M7f4LK02kadjrnnUj9pn8QSdevQnoovRMCq&b=1&f=norefer   from the colunIndex. im not sure which one it is , probably CACHED_NAME

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_STREQUENT_URI which will give you both Frequently called and Starred contacts.

Answer (score 0):

From API 21 is possible to use this: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/CallLog.Calls#CACHED_LOOKUP_URI

> CACHED_LOOKUP_URI added in API level 21 static val CACHED_LOOKUP_URI:
>   String The cached URI to look up the contact associated with the phone
>   number, if it exists.
>
> This value is typically filled in by the dialer app for the caching
>   purpose, so it's not guaranteed to be present, and may not be current
>   if the contact information associated with this number has changed.