# How to get contact image and ID for call logs?

Tags: android, calllog

I'm trying to read all call logs and display them in very organized manner. I'm able to get the call logs. But, stuck at a situation where I need to know if caller's contact already exist in my phonebook. The `CACHED_NAME` doesn't always return the value (even after having the contact saved in device).

This is how I'm getting the call logs for now:

```
private ArrayList<JSONObject> fetchCallLogs() {
    ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonArray = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Cursor cursor   = getContentResolver().query( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC" );
        int name        = cursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME );
        int number      = cursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
        int type        = cursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
        int date        = cursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE );
        int duration    = cursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION );

        while( cursor.moveToNext() ) {
            String callName     = cursor.getString( name );
            String callNumber   = cursor.getString( number );
            String callType     = cursor.getString( type );
            String callDuration = convertSecondsToHHMMSS( cursor.getString( duration ) );
            String callDateTime = DateFormat.format( "hh:mm:ss (dd MMM, yyyy)", new Date( Long.valueOf( cursor.getString( date ) ) ) ).toString();

            String dir          = "";

            switch( Integer.parseInt( callType ) ) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "Outgoing";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "Incoming";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "Missed";
                    break;
            }

            switch( Integer.parseInt( callFeature ) ) {
                case CallLog.Calls.FEATURES_VIDEO:
                    callFeaType = "Video";
                    break;
            }

            JSONObject callRecord = new JSONObject();

            try {
                callRecord.put( "name", callName );
                callRecord.put( "number", callNumber );
                callRecord.put( "type", dir );
                callRecord.put( "date", callDateTime );
                callRecord.put( "duration", callDuration );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            jsonArray.add( callRecord );
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch ( SecurityException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

I want to get the contact image and `CONTACT_ID` of logs (if they exist in the device) along with the above result.

My minimum API level is 21.

Comment: have look [this](https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/android-get-contact-details-id-name-phone-photo/)

Comment: @HemantParmar Thanks, but that link is not gonna to help much as my requirement is to get contacts details from the call logs while this link is about fetching contacts directly.

Answer (score 0):

For getting call log details, call `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI()`

```
Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(148)}, null, null);
    if (contact != null && contact.moveToNext()) {
        String lookupKey = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        int contactId = contact.getInt(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);

        Cursor calls = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_LOOKUP_URI + "=?", new String[]{contactUri.toString()}, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
        while (calls.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "type: " + calls.getString(calls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)) + ", number: " + calls.getString(calls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)) + ", " + "cached_name: " + calls.getString(calls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)) + ", " + "date: " + calls.getString(calls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
        }
    }
```

For more about call logs, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151697/5110595)

Hope it will help you!!